# Find set of vertices of max size under some restrictions

Tags: dynamic-programming, trees, greedy-algorithms

I've faced a problem and I don't know what approach I must follow, dynamic programming or greedy method, so here is the question.

Question: Given a directed tree $T=(V,\ E)$. We're required to find a set of vertices $A\subseteq V$ as big as we can such that for every two vertices $v,u\in A$ there isn't a path of length less than 3.

Note: tree can be a non-binary tree.

Example: In the image $A=[0,3,4,5]$.

[image: Example of a tree]

Comment: The length of the path between $3$ and $4$ is 2, less than 3. Is your example correct? Why is vertex $0$ not  included in $A$?

Comment: @JohnL. Thanks for the comment, it's actually an example I found, and also there is no path between $3$ and $4$, notice it's a directed graph.

Comment: "A directed graph", I was so bad at reading

Comment: Please don't re-ask questions.  If you'd like to gain more attention to your question, I suggest following the advice that was provided on that question.  After you have contributed more, another option will be to leave a bounty on the question.  Thank you!

Comment: Why it's deleted!! there's even no answer for another question, I asked it again so there could be someone who have an answer for it.